# can JavaScript regular expression cause browsers crash. How does urlPath = urlPath.replace(/(.*)+(#)$/i,'$1'); crashed chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, url, browser, crash

I added a simple regular expression in dev console and the chrome firefox and other browsers went nuts.

This is the expression. :

```
urlPath = window.location.href;
urlPath = urlPath.replace(/(.*)+(#)$/i,'$1');
```

Why does this crashed browsers ? I got no clues. Any help will be appreciated.

PS . I was trying to get rid of the hash at the end of url string to be passed to `window.location.href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can do [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) if you will get something after `#`

Change it to `/(.*)(#)$/i`

This will work

```js
console.log('12345678901234567890#12345'.replace(/(.*)(#)$/i, '$1'));
```

but this will hung your browser

```js
console.log('12345678901234567890#12345'.replace(/(.*)+(#)$/i, '$1'));
```

If you want to match everything until `#` use this `^([^#]*)`

```js
console.log('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558707/can-javascript-regular-expression-cause-browsers-crash-how-does-urlpath-urlpa#123123123'.match(/^([^#]*)/)[0]);
```